# Crop multiple pieces from a photo and save with sequential numbers

Tags: cropping, gimp

I am looking for a way to draw multiple boxes around parts of an image at one time (sort of a ctrl+select) then save each box as a separate image. I usually use GIMP for photo editing, but any free software would work.

For example, in the following image named "birds.jpg", I would like to draw a box around each individual bird then save each of the three boxes as separate images named "birds1.jpg", "birds2.jpg", and "birds3.jpg". I can crop/save as/undo multiple times, but some images have 20+ boxes to cut and there are hundreds of images. Any plug-in that may do this? Other ideas?
[image]
If this question belongs elsewhere please let me know.

Comment: So, are you asking if there is a software that will crop out "birds" from every image without you having to tell it what a "bird" is?

Comment: @TheLuckless Please post answers as answers, rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution, using the `ofn-extract-objects` script found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/)(*):

1. Make a multi-rectangle selection, one rectangle around each object (shift-click to add rectangles)
2. Copy/paste the selection to a new layer: Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V, Ctrl-Shift-N. This layer will be mostly transparent, except where you selected things.
3. `Layer>Extract objects>Extract object to files` that will extract each opaque rectangle to a file in the specified directory. The script lets you define a naming pattern for the objects (from the image name, layer name, position of objects, etc...)

(*) See bottom of page for install instructions. The ZIP contains an HTML doc.

Comment: This works perfect and exactly what I need. Be sure to read html document to get preferred naming conventions.

Comment: @tjr There is another script at the same place that can boost your productivity: `ofn-file-next`. Basically it saves, the current image, closes it and opens the next in sequences. This spares you scanning the lists in the file selector. Currently it saves the open image, but it can be made to quit it instead. Hang on...